# Escaping characters in Luxon formatter

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, luxon

I'm trying to convert duration in seconds using Luxon using the `Duration.fromMillis().toFormat()`.

I want it to output `1d2h` for one day and two hours, but I can't escape the `d` and `h`.

Here's what I tried so far

```js
Duration.fromMillis(3600 * 26 * 1000).toFormat('d\dh\h')
Duration.fromMillis(3600 * 26 * 1000).toFormat('d[d]h[h]') // Like MomentJS
```

Both doesn't work

Comment: [Formatting guide](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/docs/formatting.md) : escape characters with single quotes.

Comment: Use `.toFormat("d'd'h'h'")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated by others in the comment, you can use single quotes to escape charcters in luxon, see [Escaping](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=escaping) secction of the docs:

> You may escape strings using single quotes:
>
> ```
> DateTime.now().toFormat("HH 'hours and' mm 'minutes'"); //=> '20 hours and 55 minutes'
> ```

Here a working example:

```js
const Duration = luxon.Duration;
console.log(Duration.fromMillis(3600 * 26 * 1000).toFormat("d'd'h'h'"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that there is no way to escape a single quote: https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/649